# GET Request ignoring custom_field and showing all envelopes, how do we filter response data?

Tags: docusignapi

I setup a custom DocuSign envelope field set up to identify specific envelops. But the `GET` request simply ignores the filter and returns all envelopes in the response.

What am I doing wrong? Here is the URL:

> GET https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/1234567/envelopes?from_date=2018-01-01&PowerForm=RPT2019

Comment: i figured it out.
Request url should be in below format

GET https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/1234567/envelopes?from_date=2018-01-01&custom_field=PowerForm=RPT2019

Comment: Can you please paste you comment as an answer so that its beneficial for others?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the parameter "custom_field", correct url is:

https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/1234567/envelopes?from_date=2018-01-01&custom_field=PowerForm=RPT2019 as indicatated in comment on question.

Comment: Can you explain the difference?

Comment: the parameter "custom_field" was missing from the url